# Create Revit Sheets from Excel with multiple project parameters

Tags: excel, vb.net, revit-api, revit

Hi I have a macro that creates multiple sheets and has Name, Number, Sheet Category. The last being my own project parameter.

I can successfully create the sheets with name and number but I am having difficulty adding the value from CSV file to the project parameter "SD_Sheet Category". Below are some code grabs to help explain.

```
Public Module mSheetCreator
Public Structure structSheet
    Public sheetNum As String
    Public sheetName As String
    Public sortCategory As String
End Structure
```

Then I have a function that reads the CSV file and does the following:

```
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                'create temp sheet
                Dim curSheet As New structSheet
                curSheet.sheetNum = currentRow(0)
                cursheet.sheetName = currentRow(1)
                curSheet.sortCategory = currentRow(4)

                'add sheet to list
                sheetList.Add(curSheet)
```

Then I have a transaction that does the following:

```
For Each curSheet As structSheet In sheetList
        Try
        If sheetType = "Placeholder Sheet" Then
m_vs = ViewSheet.CreatePlaceholder(curDoc)
        Else 
m_vs = ViewSheet.Create(curDoc, tblock.Id)
m_vs.Parameter("SD_Sheet Category").Set(CStr(curSheet.sortCategory))
        End If
m_vs.Name = curSheet.sheetName
m_vs.SheetNumber = curSheet.sheetNum
```

The problem is this code:

```
m_vs.Parameter("SD_Sheet Category").Set(CStr(curSheet.sortCategory))
```

I am getting a warning that says it's an **"implicit conversion from 'String' to 'Autodesk.Revit.DB.BuiltInParameter'"** 
once I build solution

When I run the code in Revit it produces an error saying

> **"Conversion from string 'SD_Sheet Category" to type 'Integer' is not valid"**

It creates the sheets but disregards all the info in the CSV file. I know the rest of the code works as I have removed this particular line of code so I know it isn't the problem

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that as of a particular version of Revit API you cannot use .Parameter(“name”)

Because there might be two parameters with the same name.

So you need to do something more like

```
Dim cat as Parameter
```

Cat = m_vs.GetParameters(“sd_sheet category”).First()
Cat.Set(CSTR(cursht.sortCategory))

Good luck!

Comment: How would this look like? Within the code I have written it like this as you suggested.  Dim m_vs As ViewSheet  Dim cat As Parameter Cat = m_vs.GetParameters("SD_Sheet Category").First()
     then....                                                                                                                  m_vs = ViewSheet.Create(curDoc, tblock.Id)
cat.Set(CStr(curSheet.sheetCategory))  It comes up with an error that "End of statement expected". Also that 'sdorder is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". Apologies I am a beginner with VB.Net..

Comment: Sorry- I think I mis-typed, should be more like the edited version above- but apologies, I’m doing it from memory and I’m not a VB.NET person.

Comment: Thank yo so much! I have it now populating sortCategory in curSheet. But I am not seeing it Set in the sheet once they are created. I have triple checked the parameter spelling etc. The name and numbers are created but not the value contained in curSheet.sotCategory. We are so close!!

Comment: I'm not sure. Sometimes after creating an object, you have to do a manual regenerate before you can fully use it?

m_Vs.Document.Regenerate()

Comment: Thanks Alot Matt for your help. This was the solution.